# Using groovy script HttpBuilder request object, i need to validate the AEM node existence in JCR via http calls

Tags: groovy, aem

Using groovy script, i am using HTTPBuilder request object: i need to check whether the AEM Parent node exist and create.

Details: 
I am using this CLI script http://www.tothenew.com/blog/content-migration-in-aem-using-slingpostservlet/ to create nodes  while migrating contents from XML. In the XML file i have a field which contains the full path of the parent node. I need to verify whether that node exist or not. If not i need to create that node. Kindly suggest.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you are using groovy and httpbuilder module, you could simply check if a Http GET on the complete resource path url with a json extention returns a HTTP 200 or a HTTP 404. HTTP 200 means the resource exists, 404 means the node does not exist.

Following is an simple example to determine if a JCR node exists or not. Kindly note that the code below does not create a missing node and is for illustration purpose only.

```
import groovyx.net.http.HTTPBuilder
import groovyx.net.http.HttpResponseException

import static groovyx.net.http.ContentType.JSON

HTTPBuilder local = new HTTPBuilder("http://localhost:4502")
local.auth.basic("<USERNAME>", "<PASSWORD>")

def getStatus = {
    resourcePath ->
        try {
            local.get(
                    path: resourcePath + ".json",
                    contentType: JSON
            ) {
                resp, reader ->
                    return resp.status
            }
        } catch (HttpResponseException httpResponseException) {
            return httpResponseException.statusCode
        }
}

def nodePath = '/content/geometrixx-outdoors/en/men'
def httpNodeStatus = getStatus(nodePath);
if (httpNodeStatus == 404) {
    println('node : ' + nodePath + ' does not exist. creating node')
    // Code to create node
} else if (httpNodeStatus == 200) {
    println('node : ' + nodePath + ' exists')
    // Node exists
} else {
    println('HTTP Status for node : ' + httpNodeStatus)
    // handle other response codes
}
```

Comment: Thank you i did the same method :)

Answer (score 0):

You could use sling's [`ResourceUtil`](https://sling.apache.org/apidocs/sling7/org/apache/sling/api/resource/ResourceUtil.html) methods to do this for you. Look at linked java docs. Following method can come handy for this -

```
public static Resource getOrCreateResource(ResourceResolver resolver,
                                           String path,
                                           Map<String,Object> resourceProperties,
                                           String intermediateResourceType,
                                           boolean autoCommit)
                                    throws PersistenceException
```